# Data recovery from deleted partitions

Tags: partitioning, encryption, data-recovery, luks

I accidently deleted two partitions from an external usb drive. One was a blank ntsb partition with about 1gb. The other was a LUKS partition of the rest of the 250gb drive. I did not format or do anything else. When I realized what happened I tried to follow advice on the site and ran testdisk which prompted me to make a backup image which I did. I messed around but didn't manage to get a restoration to work.

Being someone who has used Ubuntu for just several months, I am fairly comfortable using terminal commands if I know what the different switches and variables mean (the first PCs I ever learned to use ran MS-DOS and PC-DOS (which means I wanted to use dir and del instead of ls and rm or use / instead of - to set variables, at least until I practiced!).However some of the advice I found for similar situations assumes a level of knowledge I just don't have or are based on previous

Could someone  give me tutorial or step-by-step on how to restore the partition? Do I need to use the backup and if so how do I proceed? I am using 20.04.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files). These partitions aren't "missing", they are gone because you deleted them.  Restore data from backups. If you don't have backups  and test disk doesn't work, you can bring the device to a data recovery specialist for the chance to restore some data at the cost of a small fortune. Stop using the device because anything you do will reduce the chances that data will be recovered.

Comment: [Testdisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) (`sudo apt install testdisk`, but you already seem to have it) should be able to reccover partitions, and has an [example guide](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Step_By_Step) on how to do it.

Comment: First, just try to restore the deleted partitions at their old sizes.  That may make all the files visible again.